# Voice controls Tizen - Samsung Tv (2016 model)

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-tv

I am trying to use voice controls on Samsung tv app (2016 model). I have found this page on the official documentation:

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/API00006/recognition_128

After including the script "deviceapis.js" I still can not access the deviceapis object.

```
"script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/webapi/1.0/deviceapis.js">/script>"
```

I am using Caph3 with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

With model 2016 you must use new library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>
```